# Why does bind_front/bind_back/not_fn/bind require Args... to be move-constructible?

Tags: c++, move-constructor, stdbind, c++23

I noticed that the `std::bind_front`/`std::bind_back`/`std::not_fn` that yields the [*perfect forwarding call wrapper*](https://eel.is/c++draft/utilities#func.require-4) all require that the function argument and argument arguments passed in *must* be move-constructible.

Take the standard specification for [`std::bind_front`](https://eel.is/c++draft/func.bind.partial) as an example:

> ```
> template<class F, class... Args>
>   constexpr unspecified bind_front(F&& f, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Mandates:
>
> ```
>   is_constructible_v<FD, F> &&
>   is_move_constructible_v<FD> &&
>   (is_constructible_v<BoundArgs, Args> && ...) &&
>   (is_move_constructible_v<BoundArgs> && ...)
> ```
>
> is `true`.

Where `FD` is the type `decay_t<F>`, and `BoundArgs` is a pack that denotes `decay_t<Args>...`.

Also, the legacy `std::bind` has the *Preconditions* that `FD` and `BoundArgs` must meet the *Cpp17MoveConstructible* requirements in [[func.bind.bind]](http://www.eelis.net/c++draft/func.bind.bind#3).

I can understand the `is_constructible_v` part since we must be able to forward arguments to the *decayed* copy inside the wrapper. But what confuses me is why we need to require these arguments to be move-constructible?

My initial guess was that this was to make the *perfect forwarding call wrapper* also move-constructible, because the standard requires that the call wrapper must meet the *Cpp17MoveConstructible* and *Cpp17Destructible* requirements according to [[func.require]](https://eel.is/c++draft/func.require#3).

However, this seems wrong, because a wrapper wrapping a non-movable object can still be move-constructible if the object has a valid copy constructor:

```
struct OnlyCopyable {
  OnlyCopyable(const OnlyCopyable&) = default;
  OnlyCopyable(OnlyCopyable&&) = delete;
};

struct Wrapper {
  OnlyCopyable copy1;
  std::tuple<OnlyCopyable> copy2;
};

static_assert(!std::move_constructible<OnlyCopyable>); 
static_assert( std::move_constructible<Wrapper>); // ok
```

It turns out that such *extra* constraint makes the standard [reject the following](https://godbolt.org/z/4n3snrT1r):

```
#include <functional>

struct OnlyCopyable {
  OnlyCopyable() = default;
  OnlyCopyable(const OnlyCopyable&) = default;
  OnlyCopyable(OnlyCopyable&&) = delete;
};

struct OnlyCopyableFun {
  OnlyCopyableFun() = default;
  OnlyCopyableFun(const OnlyCopyableFun&) = default;
  OnlyCopyableFun(OnlyCopyableFun&&) = delete;
  int operator()(auto) const;
};

int main() {
  OnlyCopyable arg;
  auto fun1 = std::bind_front([](auto) { }, arg);  // ill-formed
  OnlyCopyableFun fun;
  auto fun2 = std::bind_front(OnlyCopyableFun, 0); // ill-formed
}
```

which in my opinion, it shouldn't be as I don't see the benefits of rejecting the above.

So, why does the standard require that the argument types passed into the call wrapper factory must be move-constructible? What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: The real question is: **why would you delete the move constructor, if copy constructor is supposed to exist?** what does this pattern that you are using mean? Normally we either need objects whose contents are in no way transferable to peers(no move, no copy), or objects whose contents shall be seen through a single handle(move only), or objects whose contents can be duplicated by peers(copyable); the last category might declare move  as an optimization on function boundaries. **Your weird pattern** does not match any of the rational use cases. It is wise to ask *why this pattern is allowed?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types that are "only copyable" are not something the C++ standard recognizes as valid, reasonable code. You are allowed to do it, but such types are conceptually broken as far as the standard is concerned. As such, many features of standard library types may not work with such types.

Conceptually, move is treated as a specialized version of a copy, one that replaces copying in certain circumstances. This makes move a subset of copy. And most of the standard treats it that way: a type which can be copied can also be moved.

Again, you can technically make a type which doesn't work like this, but most of the standard will not be happy with you. You can't put them into `std::vector<T>` for example.

Comment: Thanks, this may be the answer I'm looking for. Such unreasonable types may also involve types with `explicit T(const T&)` or `T(T&)`. I wonder if the standard says anything about such "unhappy" types anywhere, although I doubt it.

Comment: Indeed, this idea is formalized in [`std::copy_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/copy_constructible), and `std::copy_constructible<OnlyCopyable>` being false is what the standard has to say about it. ;-] (I.e. that the 'copyable' concept of the OP is not what 'copyable' actually means as far as the standard is concerned)